# Replace text with html formatting using text location (text span) in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, regex, string, function

I have a string and I want to replace text with html font colors and I need to replace using a dictionary containing the start of the span (key) and the length of the span (value).  Any idea on how to do this in JS so that all my text is replaced correctly with html?

```
str = "Make 'this' become blue and also 'that'."

// color_dict contains the START of the span and the LENGTH of the word.
// i.e. this & that are both size 4.

color_dict = {6: "4", 34: "4"};

console.log(str.slice(6, 10));  //obviously this is just a slice
console.log(str.slice(34, 38));

// This is what I would like at the end.

document.write("Make '<font color='blue'>this</font>' become blue and also '<font color='blue'>that</font>'.");
```

Overall, I'd like to replace the original string with some html but using the dictionary containing the text start and length of the substring.

Thank you so much!

Comment: I have created a regex-based snippet, but it seems to be a [very weird solution](http://jsfiddle.net/bg6tyr1a/).

Comment: Thanks, @stribizhev.  I'm new to Stack Overflow. Why did you remove the regex tag even though a really good answer is regex?  I tagged it because it seemed very likely to have a answer via this route. Just wondering. Thank you!

Comment: I reverted the tag. Certainly, it is not my solution that is good :) But sincd I spent a bit of time on it, I will keep it in the comments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This uses regular expressions to get the job done. The dictionary is processed in reverse order so that the indexes for replacements won't change.

```js
var str = "Make 'this' become blue and also 'that'."

// color_dict contains the START of the span and the LENGTH of the word.
// i.e. this & that are both size 4.
var color_dict = { 6: "4", 34: "4" };

// get keys sorted numerically
var keys = Object.keys(color_dict).sort(function(a, b) {return a - b;});

// process keys in reverse order
for (var i = keys.length - 1; i > -1; i--) {
  var key = keys[i];
  str = str.replace(new RegExp("^(.{" + key + "})(.{" + color_dict[key] + "})"), "$1<font color='blue'>$2</font>");
}

document.write(str);
```

Comment: I like your reverse method - going forwards made my code three lines longer than it needed to be =)

Comment: Nice and compact solution with `regex`!

Answer (score 1):

**HTML**:

```
<div id="string">Make 'this' become blue and also 'that'.</div>
```

**jQuery**

```
var str = $("#string").text(); // get string
color_dict = [{index: 6, length: 4}, {index: 34, length: 4}]; // edited your object to instead be an array of objects

for(var i = 0; i < color_dict.length; i++) {
    str = str.substring(0, color_dict[i].index) +
          "<span style='color: blue'>" + 
          str.substring(color_dict[i].index, color_dict[i].length + color_dict[i].index) + 
          "</span>" + 
          str.substring(color_dict[i].index + color_dict[i].length);
    for(var j = i+1; j < color_dict.length; j++) {
        color_dict[j].index += color_dict[i].length + 29; // shift all further indeces back because you added a string
    }
}

$("#string").html(str); // update string
```

See the [working example on JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/uxtf8rez/).

What this does is:

1. Get the text
2. Set the dictionary
3. For each "word" in the dictionary, change the original string so that it is:

   - the text before +
   - `<div style="color: blue">`
   - the dictionary text
   - `</div>`
   - the text after the dictionary text

On a side note, the `<font>` tag and its `color` attribute are [deprecated](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_font.asp). Use CSS instead.

Answer (score 1):

You could do it like this:

```
var str = "Make 'this' become blue and also 'that'.";
var new_str = '';
var replacements = [];
var prev = 0;
for (var i in color_dict) {
    replacements.push(str.slice(prev, parseInt(i)-1));
    prev = parseInt(i) + parseInt(color_dict[i]) + 1;
    replacements.push(str.slice(parseInt(i)-1, prev));
}
for (var i = 0; i < replacements.length; i+=2) {
    new_str += replacements[i] + "<font color='blue'>" + replacements[i+1] + "</font>";
}
new_str += str.substr(-1);
console.log(new_str); 
//Make <font color='blue'>'this'</font> become blue and also <font color='blue'>'that'</font>.
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a function that would do it, it takes the string and the dictionary as arguments in the format you defined:

```
function decorateString(str, color_dict) {
    // turn into more suitable array of {start, len}
    var arr = Object.keys(color_dict).map(function (start) {
        return {
            start: parseInt(start),
            len: parseInt(color_dict[start])
        };
    });
    // sort on descending start position to ensure proper tag-insertion
    arr.sort(function(a, b) {
        return a.start < b.start;
    });
    // build new string and return it
    return arr.reduce(function(str, word) {
        return str.substr(0, word.start) 
            + "<font color='blue'>" 
            + str.substr(word.start, word.len)
            + '</font>' 
            + str.substr(word.start + word.len);
    }, str);
}
```

Use it as follows:

```
str = "Make 'this' become blue and also 'that'."
color_dict = {6: "4", 34: "4"};
document.write(decorateString(str, color_dict));
```

Here is a [JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/nk4uumze/)